Why do we have a non-zero value for PSS in case of statically compiled binary
I read about PSS (Proportional Set Size), it's the number of non-shared pages used by the application and even distribution of the shared pages. I thought it's for shared libraries. To verify i wrote a hello world program and compiled with --static and i see PSS value more than dynamic value
$ gcc hello.c -o hello --static
Rss:                 808 kB
Pss:                 804 kB

$ gcc hello.c -o hello
Rss:                1420 kB
Pss:                 103 kB

Why is Rss less for static application and Pss more?

PSS indicates the count of pages in memory, where each page is divided by the number of shares. This value can be calculated as sum of all Pss rows in /proc/PID/smaps
